# Java gson multiple json object communication with hava server socket

Tags: java, json

I try to communicate through serversocket in java. Suddenly i'm not found right answer for my simple question which is: i'd like to create json object where data build by two objects. First object is a string which is an action name, second is a java object for example a User(name, email, pass...). It's because i want to send what action need to do for the user (registration, login...) which process the server. I't shoud be like:

```
{
"action":{"type":"registration"}
"user":{"name":"Susie", "pass":"pass1"}
}
```

How can i create this in java?
My example code:

```
public static void main(String args[]){
    String action = "registration";
    User user = new User();
    user.setName("Susane");
    user.setPassword("pass1");
    Gson gson = new GsonBuilder().create();
    String json = gson.toJson(user);
    JsonParser p = new JsonParser();
    JsonObject obj = p.parse(json).getAsJsonObject();
    System.out.println(obj);
}
```

I want to send the action and the user as json string then on the server process it with gson to create User object. Which is the best way for this?

Comment: As it stands, this question is very broad. Consider narrowing down the scope to a single issue you're facing.

Comment: I realised how can i resolve my problem. It's simple just create two json object and add them to a third one then send it to the server and parse them on the server side, get the action name and the object helped by gson.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
@FXML
void signUp(ActionEvent event) {
    PrintWriter writer = MainGui.client.getWriter();

    User user = new User();
    user.setName(userNameField.getText());
    user.setPassword(pwField.getText());
    Gson gson = new GsonBuilder().create();
    String json = gson.toJson(user);
    JsonParser p = new JsonParser();
    JsonObject obj = p.parse(json).getAsJsonObject();

    JsonObject jsonAction = new JsonObject();
    jsonAction.addProperty("type", "registration");

    JsonObject sendMsg = new JsonObject();
    sendMsg.add("action", jsonAction);
    sendMsg.add("user", obj);
    writer.println(sendMsg.toString());
    writer.flush();
}
```